# Como poner una imagen dentro del header

Tags: wordpress

Estoy usando wordpress y en el header tengo el logo y el menu quisiera a este espacio colocarle una imagen ya que ahora solo puedo cambiarle de color como lo puedo hacer.

Comment: Checa [ask], a tu pregunta le hacen falta mas detalles

Answer (score 0):

En general la mayoria de temas permiten incluir una imagen a través de los menús de administracion que vienen en el apartado Apariencia->Personaliza. Sino podrias editar el tema en el que estas trabajando en Apariencia->editor de temas. Hay un archivo del tema que tienes instalado llamado header.php donde puedes modificar las caracteristicas de tu header. Para introducir una imagen puedes incluir este código html:

```
   <img src="tuimagen.jpg" alt="Texto alternativo" width="500" height="60">
```

Te recomiendo que antes de modificar directamente el tema que tienes instalado busques informacion sobre como crear un tema hijo en wordpress.